# how to log the "status" with an express middleware?

Tags: express, http, http-status-code-404, middleware

so i'm learning about express and middlewares. the request body is somehow easy; but i'm struggling with logging stuff from the response body. especially the "status"!

*there is the middleware that i used to log stuff*

```
const theLogger = (request, response, next) => {
  console.log("Method:", request.method);
  console.log("Path:  ", request.path);
  console.log("Body:  ", request.body);

  console.log("---");
  next();
};
```

edit: i'm aware of morgan. but i want to implement the functionality by my self!